# Electric stove coils scratched by pan

Tags: electric-stoves

My pan is scratching the coils on my electric stove.
What is the best pan to use so the coils do not get scratched?

Comment: Can you add an image?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like heating plates could be the solution. Note that I have never used them, and the link below is just an example; if you decide on these, shop around for the best ones for you!

[https://www.amazon.com/Nordic-Ware-Tamer-Burner-Plate/dp/B00004W4UJ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00004W4UJ)